# CSS is not working for some reason

Tags: css

Ok so let me see if I can make sense here. I am lining 3 circles in a straight line. This happens in two places on the main page of the site. I coded the first section and it lined my circles perfectly, I copy and pasted the EXACT SAME CODE and now my first line is completely messed up but the second works perfect. To  cover some bases, they are classes, not id's so that is not the issue. I have quadruple checked my brackets, spelling and any other minor incident and those are all fine as well. I am going insane here. Please if anyone could lend a hand or suggestion I would be forever grateful.
Oh and the circles are images if that helps with any needed information.

```
<div id="pages">
    <div class="projects"><a href="projects"><img src="images/projects.png" alt="projects"     align:"right"></a></div>
    <div class="services"><a href="services"><img src="images/services.png" alt="services" align:"middle"></a></div> 
    <div class="team"><a href="team"><img src="images/team.png" alt="team" align:"left"></a></div>
</div>

<div id="contact"> 
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <div class="email"><a href=""><img src="images/email.png" alt="email" align:"right"></a></div>
        <div class="phone"><img src="images/phone.png" alt="phone" align:"middle"></div>
        <div class="business"><img src="images/business.png" alt="business" align:"left"></div>
</div>


 .projects{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 75px 75px 300px;  
}

.services{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 75px 75px 75px;   
}

.team{
    float: right;
    margin: 75px 200px 75px 75px;   
}

.phone{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 75px 75px 300px;  
}

.email{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 75px 75px 75px;   
}

.business{
    float: right;
    margin: 75px 200px 75px 75px;   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: Include some code in your question

Comment: Please edit you question, and insert the code in there, not in comments.

Comment: you should provide the HTML markup as well as the CSS. better yet, create a stack snippet or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates the problem so that we can better visualize it.

Comment: Without seeing the code, my guess would be inherited extra padding / margins from some containing or previous element. Fire up your browsers dev tools and inspect the elements around your mis-behaving image.

Comment: I included the HTML but I am afraid the jsFiddle won't work, my images are local and not uploaded online to a server just yet

Answer (score 1):

With out looking at the HTML code its hard to tell what are the errors.But the most common mistake,which even the pros make sometimes, is that we forget to **change the id** of the html tags when we copy from one place to another. I assumed this could be the error in your HTML code,since the second line work perfectly good and the first one does not.

Try changing the ID may be it would help and also check that you have giving proper name to class.

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend something else besides align to accomplish your goal? I see that you have things left, right and center. What place is center+left to the browser, or left+left positioning? Try taking align out of the class or the local tag.  This is the golden ticket http://www.w3schools.com/. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp I suggest trying a look or a two at other tags that accomplish layout.